# Is the set consisting of $0$ and all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ and with degree $m$ a subspace of $P(\mathbb{F})$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the set consisting of $0$ and all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ and with degree $m$ a subspace of $P(\mathbb{F})$?

I want to say no, since it seems that it is not closed under addition.

Consider $p$,$q$ with $$\begin{align}  p(z) = a_0+a_1z+ \cdots + a_mz^m,\\q(z) = b_0+b_1z+\cdots-a_mz^m,\\ \\ \text{where } a_m \neq 0. \end{align}$$

Then $p(z)+q(z) = (a_0+b_0)+(a_1+b_1)z+\cdots +(a_{m-1}+b_{m-1})z^{m-1}$, whose degree is less than or equal to $m-1$.

Comment: If the degree requirement is exactly $m$, then indeed it isn't a subspace (unless $m = 0$ and $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Z}_2$). If it's $\leqslant m$, it is a subspace. Carefully check the wording to see which answer is expected.

Comment: "With degree equal to $m$". Just double-checked my textbook.

Comment: You are correct.  It is *not* a subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

The space of all polynomials with coefficients in a field $\mathbb{F}$ is a vector space (better still, it is an algebra). For a subset of this vector space to be a subspace, it needs to contain the zero vector, be closed under multiplication by scalars (elements of $\mathbb{F}$), and be closed under addition. The proposed subset satisfies the first two conditions but not the third, as you have shown, so it is not a subspace. However, if we consider the space of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ and degree less than or equal to $m$, we do obtain a subspace - in general $\operatorname{deg}(f + g) \leq \max\{\operatorname{deg}(f), \operatorname{deg}(g)\}$.